# How to create a `HashSet<Character>` contains '0'-'9' using Stream API?

Tags: java, set, java-stream

I'm trying to create a `Set<Character>` contains value from `'0'` to `'9'`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
var totalSet = IntStream.range('1', '9')
    .map(i -> (char) i)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // type of totalSet is `Set<Integer>`
```

But I found that the type of `totalSet` is `Set<Integer>`. How can I achieve the desired result?

I'm using JDK 17.

Comment: `"123456789".chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).collect(Collectors.toSet())` or even just `Set.of('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use operation [`mapToObj()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj(java.util.function.IntFunction)) (*not* `map()`) to transform `IntStream` into a `Stream<Character>`.

When you apply `.map(i -> (char) i)` in the `IntStream` (*a stream of primitive* `int` *values*) it only performs primitive conversion from `int` to `char` (***reminder:*** [`char`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) *is a numeric type*), and then the result would be promoted back into `int`.

And when you apply `boxed()` on the `IntStream` you're getting `Stream<Integer>` (*a stream of integer wrappers*).

```
Set<Character> totalSet = IntStream.range('1', '9')
    .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```